# Feedback on sliding through keys in android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am using lift-to-type custom keyboard for android. I added vibration feedback in the 'onPress' method. But it gives the feedback only for the first key pressed, and not when I scroll/slide through the neighbouring keys without lifting the finger. How should I get the feedback for the subsequent keys pressed?